ASP.NET Core IIS redirects recursively redirects requests to login page
I have a website which uses cookie authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opts => {
    opts.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opts.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opts => {
        // ...
        opts.LoginPath = "/login.html";
    });

This works correctly when served by the Visual Studio dev server. Unauthenticated requests get a 302 redirect to login page response, and the request for the login page goes through.
It is deployed to IIS with this web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.web>
            <!--<authentication mode="Forms">
                <forms loginUrl="IISAppName/login.html" />
            </authentication>-->
        </system.web>
        <system.webServer>
            <!--<security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                </authentication>
            </security>-->
            
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="./Server.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="C:\file.log" hostingModel="inprocess" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>

I tried with and without the commented out parts. It is in an IIS application in the default site (port 80).
But now, requests for http://localhost/IISAppName/login.html recursively redirect to /IISAppName/login.html:

The OnRedirectToLogin event is raised each time.
How do I get it to work in IIS as expected?

Change it from an IIS Virtual Directory to a proper IIS Application Scope. Ditch the <location> elements too (they're redundant when using path=".").

Woops. It was actually an application, have edited my question

According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, do you want your requests to not be redirected recursively? if so, you can try to use failed request tracking to view detailed information, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Unauthenticated requests to an endpoint should 302 redirect to the login page, but a request for the login page should not redirect to itself. Edited my post for clarity.

Then you need to find out why the request for the login page is redirected to itself. failed request tracking is a good choice.

I found some answers myself.
TLDR: try dotnet publishing instead of using output dir first
Firstly, adding
<location path="login.html">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>

stopped the 302 redirects. But my site was still not working because I was just using the default bin output, instead of dotnet publish. When using dotnet publish got 404s for the login page, but removing the above xml made it work as expected.
